# jQuery slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to work around to get my slider to work but I don't know what the problem is. I've done it in other projects but with different versions of jQuery-UI

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range-max").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    value: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val($("#slider-range-max").slider("value"));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post" class="form-group">
  <h3 class=""><?php echo "Welcome ".$name?></h3>
  <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your review here" required maxlength="200"></textarea>
  <p>
    <label for="amount">Minimum number of bedrooms:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
  <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the expected output and what output are you getting? Are there any console errors?

Comment: No errors in the console, really confused :\

Comment: Also, i'm trying to get a slider that would give a range between 1 and 5

Comment: I ran the code and I'm getting the slider. See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47m8n704/1/).

Comment: What is it supposed to be doing that it's not doing (or not doing that it should be)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there're two links to jquery one at the header and the other one is at the bottom of the document.

Thanks